# What virtualization platform does provide dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I need a virtualization platform for Linux host that supports `Dynamic Memory Allocation`. By [Dynamic Memory Allocation](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2016/11/28/overcoming-the-ram-bottleneck.aspx) I don't mean [Memory Ballooning](http://www.vfrank.org/2013/09/18/understanding-vmware-ballooning/) where we can request memory from a running VM (Virtual Machine), to allocate it to another running VM (if any). I need a mechanism that's capable of dynamically allocating a VM just as memory amount as necessary for it to operate. For example, if I have defined 4GB of memory for a guest Windows setting, but it needs no more than 1GB, the remaining 3GB would be available to the host Linux, NOT to the virtualization platform so that it can be allocated to another running VM.

Comment: Suggest you focus on KVM, Virtuozzo, VMware (Workstation) Player, VMware Server, VMware Workstation 5.5 and up, and Xen. Sifted through a list of virtualization SW running under Linux and compared against virtualization SW claiming dynamic memory allocation.